# Aptana 3 Remote FTP timeout

Tags: ftp, aptana, remote-server

Question is simple. Is there an option in Aptana 3 Studio, that will keep alive an ftp/remote connection ? Everytime i'm taking a break for like 4-5 minutes my connection is lost, and when I try to open any file on server, Aptana hangs and i need to alt-ctrl-del it. It's really annoying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set how long the FTP connection is kept alive with the following setting:

`Window > Preferences > Aptana Studio > Publishing > FTP`

Or you can simply type `ftp` into the search box in the upper left hand corner of the `Preferences` Dialog Box

At the bottom of the Dialog Box:

`The number of minutes to keep the FTP connection open:` **Set number of minutes**

[image]

Comment: Thank you for answer, that was excactly what I was looking for.

Comment: That doesn't work when deploying; with syncing enabled, every time you save a file it opens a new connection, transfers the file, and closes the connection.  With frequent edits this causes some webhosts (i.e. HostGator) to block you as an attacker.  Is there a way to make this option actually be respected for ALL connections - i.e. deployment as well - so it doesn't reconnect for every file save?